# Create jar with another project

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to create a Jar from two projects: the current project, and a project named 'baseProj'.
I can create a Jar from the current project, but how do I add data from another project?
I tried the commented lines, but there is no such thing

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def n = variant.buildType.name
    def f = variant.productFlavors.get(0).name

    def task = project.tasks.create "jar${f.capitalize()}${n.capitalize()}", Jar
    task.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
    //task.dependsOn project(':baseProj').javaCompile -??

    task.from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
    task.exclude '**/R.class'

    //task.from project(':baseProj').javaCompile.destinationDir -??

    artifacts.add('archives', task);
}
```